# UITextField and autolayout in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, autolayout

I designed my application with autolayout. I have 2 components, a logo in the center of my view and a `UITextField` which is hidden initially. In my `viewDidLoad` it animates and changes the logo's frame and then sets the `UITextField`'s hidden value to NO. The issue is, when I click on the `UITextField` it changes logo's frame back to its default value, the same value as when the application first starts.

Comment: Are you changing the logo frame size by changing the NSLayoutContstrains values??

Comment: When you use autolayout you must not change the frame property. If you do, it may do what you intend it to do but will be reset when the constraints are applied the next time.

Comment: I changed Constrain and working good thank you.